# Exiftool on WSL cannot write

Tags: ubuntu, exif

Using **exiftool** on **Windows Subsystem for Linux** (WSL, Ubuntu) I can print exif data:

```
# exiftool test.pdf

ExifTool Version Number         : 10.80
File Name                       : test.pdf
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 279 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2020:04:28 23:00:41+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2020:04:28 23:08:51+02:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2020:04:28 23:00:41+02:00
File Permissions                : rwxrwxrwx
File Type                       : PDF
File Type Extension             : pdf
MIME Type                       : application/pdf
PDF Version                     : 1.7
Linearized                      : No
Warning                         : Info object (11 0 obj) not found at 285226
```

However, **I cannot change or delete them**, e.g. the following command throws an error which I do not understand.

```
# exiftool -all= test.pdf

Error: Info object (11 0 obj) not found at 285226 - test.pdf
    0 image files updated
    1 files weren't updated due to errors
```

I was not sure about write privileges, so I copied (duplicated, from within WSL) the (Windows-created) original file and renamed it to test.pdf, but this did not solve the problem.
I found the following suggestions, but they did not solve the issue either:

- shortening path
- https://beepily.com/2011/10/fixing-messed-up-metadata-with-exiftool/
  (exiftool -all= -tagsfromfile @ -all:all -unsafe )

Comment: Looks like the file is either broken or not fully readable by exiftool. Also note that the man page mentions this: "Changes to PDF files by ExifTool are reversible (by deleting the update with "-PDF-update:all=") because the original information is never actually deleted from the file. So ExifTool alone may not be used to securely edit metadata in PDF files."

Comment: It may also be related to [this](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=11130.0) and [this](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=11029.0). The error you get seems to have been fixed in ExifTool 11.94.

Comment: @Antonio +1 will try asap as I get to PC (traveling)

Answer (score 3):

Try executing the command with the `-v` option. If you get an `Object was freed` warning, then the error is probably related to the problem reported in [this](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=11029.0) and [this](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=11130.0) threads which was fixed in ExifTool 11.94 according to the posts by the author of ExifTool:

> The problem occurs because the pointer in the cross-reference table written by the Microsoft software doesn't point directly to the referenced object.  Instead, it points to the line before the object.  So I will patch ExifTool to skip leading blank lines, which should solve the problem.

As pointed out by @Freddy in his comment also note that changes to PDF files made by ExifTool alone are reversible.